# Joining a third table, but not a typical join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my query right now:

```
 SELECT
 a.stacct, b.hacct, a.stfrqcode, b.thfrqcode 
 FROM st a
 LEFT JOIN th b
 ON b.hacct = a.stacct
```

The issue: I have a third table that has the relation of each stfrqcode to each thfrqcode (for example ax = d4); problem is how do I pull back everything and tell if they match? In the reference table there are two columns stfrqcode and thfrqcode -- they have different values in each column.

### Schema

### table st:

stacct,

stfrqcode

### table th:

hacct,

thfrqcode

### table frqcodes:

thfrqcode,

stfrqcode

### data from frqcodes

ns          x00
ed          x22
zs          x33
ao          x44

Result set should be:
stacct, hacct, and basically a yes/no if there is a match between stfrqcode and thfrqcode.

Comment: What is `ax=d4` supposed to mean?  I don't see that anywhere in what you have shown us.  Can you please post the structure of all three tables, sample data and what you would like output?

Comment: ax = d4 are equivalent values from frqcodes table; basically that's what I need to know in the resultset whether or not they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your table structure (with some dummy values I created):

Table st

```
stacct    stfrqcode
fred         A
mary         B
joseph       C
```

Table th

```
hacct     thfrqcode
fred         J
mary         H
```

Table relation

```
stfrqcode   thfrqcode
   A            J
   B            Q
```

and you are wanting this solution (I removed hacct as the value can only be either equal to stacct or null if there is no match):

```
stacct    match
fred       yes
mary       no
joseph     no
```

this is the query I would try:

```
SELECT
 a.stacct, (CASE WHEN c.strfrqcode IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END) AS match
 FROM st a
 LEFT JOIN th b
 ON b.hacct = a.stacct
 LEFT JOIN relation c
 ON c.strfrqcode = a.strfrqcode and c.thfrqcode = b.thrfrqcode and b.thrfrqcode IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
   a.stacct
  ,b.hacct
  ,case when c.stfrqcode is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end IsMatch
 from st a
  left outer join th b
   on b.hacct = a.stacct
  left outer join ThirdTable c
   on c.stfrqcode = a.stfrqcode
    and c.thfrqcode = b.thfrqcode
```

...might be some typos in there, I couldn't debug it.

Comment: Pretty sure that's the idea I am looking for; however, the data in frqcodes doesn't match exactly. So how would that case statement work? Would I need to specify each value?

Comment: If you can't do a strict equality comparison, how do you identify an appropriate match? And then work that logic into the query somehow. It totally depends on what "the data... doesn't match exactly" means.

Answer (score 0):

If your frqcodes table isn't necessarily unique on (stfrqcode, thfrqcode), or just because you can, you may like to try an exists clause in the select list:

```
SELECT a.stacct, b.hacct, a.stfrqcode, b.thfrqcode,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM frqcodes AS c
                         WHERE c.stfrqcode = a.stfrqcode
                           AND c.thfrqcode = b.thfrqcode)
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
       END AS relationship_exists
FROM st a
     LEFT JOIN th b
     ON b.hacct = a.stacct
```